# turtlebot3: does imu have affect to odometry?

Tags: navigation, odometry, ros-kinetic, opencr, turtlebot3

[image: Rosanswers logo]

turtlebot3 question here.
I have customized turtlebot3 waffle.
I am getting odometry and imu topics from him.
I am using odometry data for rtabmap.
I changed position of opencr on robot's base.

I want to know, how odometry is made in opencr code. does imu have any affect to odometry data?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/339305/turtlebot3:-does-imu-have-affect-to-odometry?/) by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) on ROS Answers with karma: 83 on 2019-12-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

yes, it does:

https://github.com/ROBOTIS-GIT/OpenCR/blob/c1cd84c10aa6d7886cb890a884ed39fd72257e05/arduino/opencr_arduino/opencr/libraries/turtlebot3/examples/turtlebot3_waffle/turtlebot3_core/turtlebot3_core.ino

---

Originally posted by [june2473](https://answers.ros.org/users/44408/june2473/) with karma: 83 on 2019-12-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0